# css file stops working when using .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to make clean urls for my website so i created a .htaccess file as following :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^product/(\w+)/(\w+)$ product.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^product/(\w+)/(\w+)$ product.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^store/(\w+)/(\w+)$ Store.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^store/(\w+)/(\w+)$ Store.php?id=$1
```

Now it works fine , but when i strat the page i see that the design is working with no css and no images , so what do you think is the problem ??

Best Regards

Comment: It depends on where your css and js files are. Use your browsers developer tools to see where the browser is looking for these files

Comment: I would say thet your first 2 rules might be braking the css. Try commenting them out and see what happens.

Comment: i trying to open this url : http://localhost/template/product/75/22

Comment: and the browser is trying to find the css at Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost/template/product/75/css/stylesheet.css

Answer (score 2):

Problem is probably in relative path of your CSS file (and images etc). Use absolute path or base tag in header

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/" />
```

Comment: i tried it  and the browser is still trying to load it from Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost/template/product/75/css/stylesheet.css
 when i try to open this url :  localhost/template/product/75/22

Comment: And on your disc path {localhost_root}/template/product/75/css/stylesheet.css exists?

Comment: the css is in  {localhost_root}/template/css/stylesheet.css

Comment: And product.php and Store.php are in localhost_root?

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML page, prefix the links to your CSS files with `/`.

So, if you have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
```

Change it to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/stylesheet.css" />
```

This make the path to the CSS absolute, so that it will find the CSS no matter what "folder" the browser thinks it is in.